# Form in django form.as_p different

Tags: python, django

what form.to_p exacly return?

I mean

this code:

```
            <form action="{{ action }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" name="title_field" id="form.title}}"/>
                        <input type="text" name="author_field" id="form.author }}"/>
                        {{ form.content }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </form>
```

doesn't work, instead of this code works:

```
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </form>
```

Of course in the first case I can stylize in html/css specific fields..

@edit

by working I mean send forward. In first second doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

Forms have a few ***optional*** rendering options in django: as_p, as_table, as_ul

Without any rendering options:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Will render a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input>
<input>
<input>
...
</form>
```

Adding the rendering option as_p just wraps the input fields in paragraph tags. So adding the as_p here:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Will render a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><input></p>
<p><input></p>
<p><input></p>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what `{{ form.as_p }}` outputs, you can click 'view source' in your browser and see the rendered html.

I would not recommend rendering the fields manually as in your first example. It's easy to make mistakes. For example you have forgotten the opening `{{` in `id="form.title}}"`.

If you need to add a custom class to the input, you can do this by [changing the field's widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances). Alternatively, you might find [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) useful.

Comment: I wasn't saying that adding `{{` would fix the problem, it was an example that rendering inputs manually is error-prone. We can't tell what `{{ form.as_p }}` outputs because we don't know what the form is. You don't need our help to find the problem - just use 'view source' in your browser, then compare it to your first template.